# If $F(0)=\pi/3$ and $F(\pi/6)=\pi$, Find $\int_0^{\pi/6}\sin(F(x))f(x)dx=?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am dusting off my maths skills just for fun, specifically I am doing some old Calculus problems I used to do at school like 10 years ago.

I have come across this problem:

> If $F(0)=\pi/3$ and $F(\pi/6)=\pi$, how much is
> $\int_0^{\pi/6}\sin(F(x))f(x)dx\,?$

What I have tried so far is applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, first and second parts:

FTC I : $F(x) = \int_a^xf(t)dt$, where $f$ is continuous and real-valued in $[a,b]$, and $F$ is defined for any $x$ within such interval.

FTC II: $\int_a^bf(x)dx = F(b)-F(a)$, assuming $f(x)$ is Riemann-integrable in $[a,b]$.

In my problem, $a=0$ and $b=\pi/6$, but this is as far as I can get with my current knowledge, because in the problem the function $f(x)$ is inside the $\sin$ function and multiplying itself.

Any guidance or hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that $F'(x)=f(x)$? If that's the case, I believe  $\int_0^{\pi/6}\sin(F(x))f(x)dx=\cos 0-\cos \pi/6$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $u=F(x)$, so we have

$$du=dF(x)=F'(x)dx=f(x)dx$$

then

$$\int_0^{\pi/6}\sin(F(x))f(x)dx=\int_{F(0)}^{F(\pi/6)} \sin u ~du=\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi} \sin u ~du=\frac{3}2$$

Comment: Thank you a lot, but not sure how you went from the first integral to the second (i.e., how you transformed the start and end values from $0$ to $F(0)$ and from $\pi/6$ to $F(\pi/6)$). The rest is crystal clear to me but I wouldn't have been able to pull that one off.

Comment: If $x=0$, when you transform $x$ to $u$, because $u=F(x)$, so when $x=0$, it means $u=F(x=0)=F(0)$. Similar for $x=\pi/6$ case.